# Nondeterministic finite automata (NFA) correction

Tags: regex, string, algorithm, logic, nfa

I am trying to solve a question about NFA. The instructions are as following: Alphabet {a, b, c}. • L1 is all strings that their last character is the same as their fifth-last character. For instance, the string aaacbacbca should be accepted, because the fifth-last character and the last character are both a. The string ccaab should be rejected because the fifth-last character is c and the last character is b. Here is with what I came up, but I am really beginner in this topic and I am not sure whether is correct or not:
[image]

Comment: I imagine the regex would be `^[abc]*([abc])[abc]{3}\1$`, but that has a back-reference which you would have to expand into 3 branches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The automata you have at the moment accepts only the strings that end with `acbca`. Here are steps to arrive to the solution:

- change the automata you have such that it would accept all strings which have last and five-to-last symbol `a`
- do the same for the symbols `b`, `c`
- combine the 3 automata

Answer (score 1):

You were almost right, but the automata you drew was only to accept strings ending in `acbca`.  This one will accept the strings you want

```
a,b,c     a      a,b,c   a,b,c   a,b,c    a     a,b,c
,--->[q0]--->[q1]--->[q2]--->[q3]--->[q4]--->{q5}----+>[q16]-----.
|    /|   b      a,b,c   a,b,c   a,b,c    b     a,b,c|   ^ a,b,c |
`---´ +----->[q6]--->[q7]--->[q8]--->[q9]--->{q10}---+   `-------´
      |   c      a,b,c   a,b,c   a,b,c    c     a,b,c|
      `----->[q11]-->[q12]-->[q13]-->[q14]-->{q15}---´
```

States like `{q5}` are accepting states, while states like `[q0]` are not accepting.  The meaning of `q16` is to make sure that strings that have two equal letters distant 4 characters but not ending there, sink to a non accepting state.  Same might be for letters `b,c` in state `[q4]`, for letters `a,c` in state `[q9]`, and for letters `a,b` in state `[q14]`, but for clarity of the drawing, I have omitted them.